# Checking if range of values pertaining to a single specified value is available in a List

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, linq

I'm currently writing logic to check if a given string that contains a certain range of values corresponding to certain criteria.

The logic I am trying to implement is as follows, there is a certain variable  `string value = "12";` with the assigned value as below, Given that I have a List of Values which I will have, I want to check if there will be any values with 12.x and this could be something like 12.0.1 or 12.2 Simply put want to check if the List contains anything with 12.Something (12 point something)

I have not been successful in how I can improve the said behavior Would really appreciate if someone has any idea if its possible to implement this

My code of the attempt is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    values.Add("12.0.1");
    values.Add("12.2");

    string value = "12";

    //Logic to check if values with 12.x / 12.something is available 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    values.Add("12.0.1");
    values.Add("12.2");

    string value = "12";

    var isExists = values.Any(x => x.StartsWith($"{value}."));
}
```

Comment: @Selvin Ok, what's the problem?? `"120.2".StartsWith("12.")` returns false.

Comment: @Selvin What should the code return for `values` contain the only string `"120"`? It should return `False` and my solution returns `False` too.

Comment: @Hadi do we actually need that . at the end tho ?

Comment: @Devss In the mentioned pattern yes. If you are looking for example version `"12.x"`, you should search for constant part of string that in your case is "12."

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
values.Where(v => v.StartsWith("12."));
```

This will return all values that meet the criteria. If you want to know how many there are, use `Count` instead of `Where` and if you only want to know if at least one value meets the criteria but you are not interested in the value itselft, use `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LINQ to Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects).

If you just want to check if the value presents in the list, you can write:

```
values.Any(e => e.StartsWith(value));
```

If you want to know, how many times the value presents in the list:

```
values.Count(e => e.StartsWith(value));
```